# ManagedCuda kernel cannot find curand.h

Tags: c#, cuda, managed-cuda, curand

I'm trying to use [ManagedCuda](https://kunzmi.github.io/managedCuda/) to compile a kernel that uses the [currand library](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html). However, I cannot find a way to tell the CudaRuntimeCompiler how to find curand.h.

If I remove the '`#include <curand.h>`' line, everything works. However with it I get:

```
Exception: ErrorCompilation: Compilation error.
Test(1): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "curand.h"

1 catastrophic error detected in the compilation of "Test".
Compilation terminated.
```

Using a fully qualified include (`#include <C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\include\curand.h>`) gets me a bit further, so it's obviously just a case of telling the compiler where to look.

```
Exception: ErrorCompilation: Compilation error.
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\include\curand.h(59): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "cuda_runtime.h"
```

I've tried adding the folders to the path, to no avail.

Anyone know where this can be set? (Or know of an alternative package to ManagedCuda?)

All code below.

C# Code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rtc = new CudaRuntimeCompiler(GetKernel(), "Test");

            string[] compileArgs = new string[0];

            try
            {
                rtc.Compile(compileArgs);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string log = rtc.GetLogAsString();
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {e.Message}");
                Console.WriteLine(log);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            rtc.Dispose();
        }

        static string GetKernel()
        {
            return File.ReadAllText("Kernel.c");
        }
```

Kernel.c

```
#include <curand.h>

extern "C"
{
    __global__ void DoNothing()
    {
    }
}
```

With MangedCuda-100 (10.0.31) and ManagedCuda-NVRTC (10.0.31) installed from NuGet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="ManagedCuda-100" version="10.0.31" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="ManagedCuda-NVRTC" version="10.0.31" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

Comment: https://github.com/kunzmi/managedCuda/blob/e796f78f8ec72bfea1dfe1974f1aaa5d758ef020/NVRTC/CudaRuntimeCompiler.cs#L28 -- as per the linked duplicate, you have to supply include files/sources as separate arguments to the NVRTC session

Comment: @talonmies Why has this been marked as a duplicate to a question that does not even mention ManagedCuda? I don't have a problem compiling currand into ptx files, but I can't get it to compile using ManagedCuda. The 'solution' in that question is 'generate random numbers on the CPU and upload it' which is madness and doesn't answer the question here.

Comment: @talonmies Note, this is *not* a cuda problem, nvcc works fine, its a problem with ManagedCuda.